# Getting Average by Inputting number in Java

Tags: java, android-activity

Hi I'm doing an java activity that Computes the average input. Here's my Code:

```
   System.out.print("Enter How Many Inputs: ");
        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        int arr[] = new int [num1];

        for (int i = 0; i<num1;i++){

            System.out.print("Input Value #" + (i+1) + ":" );
            arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());


        }
```

This codes is working now my problem is how can i compute the average of the inputted number. thanks!

```
             System.out.print("The average inputed Number is: ");
            {  What Statement will i use to get the Average?   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You get the average the same way you did back in high school.

Add the items together to get a sum, then divide them by their count.

It is a good idea to have a variable to hold the count and sum.  Then your average looks like

```
average = sum / count;
```

Comment: When learning how to program, it is pretty easy to lose sight of the big picture; because, you are dealing with the mechanics of how to program.  If you get stuck like this again, ask yourself what the program needs to do without worrying about how it needs to be written.  Then you will have the answer in vague "parts".  Each part is conceptually smaller than the program, so it is easier to write.  Then repeat the process, like so "Ok, now I need to get a sum, how can I sum all the elements in `arr[]`?"  Breaking problems down is a very important _learned_ skill.  Practice it. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.print("Enter How Many Inputs: ");
        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        int arr[] = new int [num1];
        int sum = 0; //<---new

        for (int i = 0; i<num1;i++){

            System.out.print("Input Value #" + (i+1) + ":" );
            arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
            sum += arr[i]; // <----new

        }
        int average = sum / num1; // <--- new
```

Answer (score 0):

Define `sum` as `int` and `average` as `double`.

```
  int sum = 0; 
   for (int i = 0; i<num1;i++){
        System.out.print("Input Value #" + (i+1) + ":" );
        arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        sum+ = arr[i];
    }

    double average = sum/num1;
```